# Get access token using Refresh token through google API using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

when the callback URL is called I am getting the token from google API and store it in MongoDB.

```
exports.authorizedGoogle = async (req, res, next) => {
  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL
  );
  
    const code = req.query.code;
    const userId = req.query.state;
    const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    var oauth2 = google.oauth2({
      auth: oauth2Client,
      version: "v2",
    });
    const { data } = await oauth2.userinfo.get();
    if (data && tokens && code && userId) {
      const googleUser = await GoogleAccount.create({
        refreshToken: tokens.access_token,
        id_token: tokens.id_token,
        isActive: true,
        user: userId,
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        googleId: data.id,
        imageLink: data.picture,
      });
      res.status(200).json({ status: "success" });
    }
};
```

now when I am trying to get the access token using refresh token and google API it's throwing an error " token has been expired or revoked".

```
const currentGoogleAccount = await GoogleAccount.findOne({
      user: userId,
      isActive: true,
    });


    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL
    );

     oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: currentGoogleAccount.refreshToken,
    });

    const drive = google.drive({
      version: "v3",
      auth: oauth2Client,
    });
```

Comment: 1. did it expire after seven days?  2. is your app still in the testing phase?

Comment: the App is not in the testing phase and it is expiring after a few minutes

Comment: It shouldnt be access tokens expire after an hour,  refresh tokens are good for seven days with testing apps.   Theres something else wrong if your loosing access after a few minutes.   Have a look at the drive sample https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs   and dont use v2

Comment: Have you checked on how the quickstart handles the token refresh? If applied as on the Quickstart, do you have the same behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the line where we storing a google account in MongoDB I was referencing access token to refresh the token field.

```
  const googleUser = await GoogleAccount.create({
        refreshToken:tokens.refresh_token, //tokens.access_token this was the issue so changed access_token to refresh_token 
        id_token: tokens.id_token,
        isActive: true,
        user: userId,
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        googleId: data.id,
        imageLink: data.picture,
      });
```